# AngularJS ng-click not displaying ng-show message

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have searched for an answer to my problem and not sure why my ng-click is not firing the ng-show message for me.

I have my controller function:

```
$scope.showLogoutMessage = function() {
    $scope.logoutmsg = true;
};
```

My Login page html:

```
<input id="j_password" type="password" name="j_password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="loginData.j_password" required />
<small style="color:red;" class="error" ng-show="logoutmsg">
    You have been logged out.
</small>
```

Then I fire this ng-show from a different jsp page:

```
<li><a ng-controller="LoginController" id="logout" href="javascript;;" 
ng-click="showLogoutMessage()">Log Out</a></li>
```

I have logged out messages in my controller and the value 'logoutmsg' is being set fine but just won't display my message for some reason. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you sure that function is called on click? why are you using href=javascript;;? ng-click already prevents the default action on links.

Comment: Could you please post the whole code, looks like button click belongs to a different controller and message belong to other.

Comment: If it's in a different jsp page then it's going to be a different scope.

Comment: @JamesWaddington is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: `different jsp page` doesn't make sense. Is this not a single page app?

Comment: @charlietfl I have a index.jsp which dynamically displays either login.jsp or home.jsp depending on user status, and in home.jsp i have a ng-view swapping html pages inside the same container

Comment: The normal way in angular would be to use angular's routing so that it handles those two pages. Let it switch out the template and just fetch the data from your server. That way you can maintain your angular state across page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Is the first code that you have written is in same controller (LoginController). if not

give a name to that controller

```
    <input id="j_password" type="password" name="j_password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="loginData.j_password" required />
    <div id='message' ng-controller='MesssageCtrl'  >
    <small style="color:red;" class="error" ng-show="logoutmsg">
        You have been logged out.
    </small> </div>
```

then

```
$scope.showLogoutMessage = function() {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('message')).scope().logoutmsg = true;
};
```

if this works then fine else u can try adding one more line in above function

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('message')).scope().$apply()
```

Comment: `$document` is a jQlite object and has no method `getElementById()`. There are a variety of more testable approaches than looking for a specific elemnt scope also

Comment: sorry typo mistake now i corrected, thanks for informing @charlietfl